# How to use jq to obtain the value of a GitLab issue label

Tags: json, gitlab, jq

GitLab allows one to attach labels to issues. I would like to use jq to dig into the JSON representation of these labels. Here's the labels section of the JSON file for one issue:

```json
"labels": [
   "AI::Assessed",
   "Pri::1 - High",
   "Type::Investigation",
   "v::Backlog"
]
```

How, with jq, can I get at the value of the "v" label, which here is "Backlog"?

Note that the number of labels varies from issue to issue. The `::` signifies that a label is a *scoped* label.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: The label itself is `v::Backlog`, not `v`. There's nothing wrong with wanting to filter for scoped labels and removing the scope though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scan` (or `capture`) :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '{"labels": [
   "AI::Assessed",
   "Pri::1 - High",
   "Type::Investigation",
   "v::Backlog"
]}' | jq -r '.labels[] | scan("v::(.*)")[]'

# Output : Backlog
```

Comment: Terrific!  Thank you, Philippe.

Comment: Using `scan` could avoid the aux labeling (if this mattered): `.labels[] | scan("v::(.*)")[]`

Comment: @pmf Indeed better, updated.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial and straightforward solution with [`startswith`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#startswith) and [substring/string-slicing](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-string-slice):

```
.labels[] | select(startswith("v::"))[3:]
```

If you need it to be more dynamic:

```
jq --arg scope 'v::' '.labels[] | select(startswith($scope))[$scope|length:]'
```